# When and why are Google Cloud Spanner table and column names case-sensitive?

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

Spanner documentation says:

> Table and column names:
>
> - Can be between 1-128 characters long. Must start with an uppercase or    lowercase letter.
> - Can contain uppercase and lowercase letters,    numbers, and underscores, but not hyphens.
> - Are case-insensitive. For example, you cannot create tables named mytable and MyTable in the same database or columns names mycolumn and
>     MyColumn in the same table.

https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/data-definition-language#table_statements

Given that, I have no idea what this means:

> Table names are usually case insensitive, but may be case sensitive
>   when querying a database that uses case sensitive table names.

https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/lexical#case-sensitivity

In fact it seems that table names are case-sensitive, for example:

[image: Spanner tables]

Queries fail if we don't match the case shown in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an error in the documentation. Table names are case insensitive in cloud spanner. I'll follow up with the docs team.

Edit: Updated docs https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/data-definition-language#naming_conventions

Comment: The information I got is "Spanner schema object names are case sensitive in DDL definitions and queries in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA, but object names cannot differ only by case. Spanner schema object names are case insensitive in SQL queries.

The reason is to allow the user to choose a preferred capitalization style for object names, and that is enforced in references in DDL and in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

It also removes ambiguity when querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables -- the user has to specify the exact case or use case-insensitive matching, just like when matching in other SQL queries"

Comment: Are they going to add that to Google's documentation? I would like to link to that from our documentation.

Comment: Yes, maybe not exactly this statement, but something to that effect.

Comment: Can you post a URL?

Comment: The docs has been updated. https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/data-definition-language#naming_conventions

Answer (score -1):

I add a couple of examples, so we can see the diference.

Table names are case sensitive,  In this example, It does not matter, there is only one table:

Example 1:

SELECT *

FROM Roster

WHERE LastName = @myparam

returns all rows where LastName is equal to the value of query parameter myparam.

But for Example 2, if we comparing two tables, or make other kind of queries, using tables.

SELECT id, name

FROM Table1 except select id, name

FROM Table2

It will give you everything in Table1 but not in Table2.

Comment: I don't understand how that's relevant.